# How to read and flat/normalize a sequence of tables from pandas read_html?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I was reading about [read_html](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_html.html) pandas functionality, since I am working in extracting some tables from the web, so when I do:

```
import pandas as pd
url_mcc = 'link.com.html'
dfs = pd.read_html(url_mcc)
dfs
```

I get the following list:

```
[                                        Presentation  \
 0  0.4 mg/mL, 1 mL single-dose vial, package of 2...   
 1  1 mg/mL, 1 mL single-dose vial, package of 25 ...   

   Availability and Estimated Shortage Duration  \
 0             Available for NDC 00517-0401-25.   
 1                                    Available   

                                  Related Information  \
 0  American Regent is currently releasing the 0.4...   
 1  American Regent is currently releasing the 1mg...   

    Shortage Reason (per FDASIA)  
 0  Demand increase for the drug  
 1                         Other  ,
                                         Presentation  \
 0  0.1 mg/mL; 10 mL Luer-Jet Prefilled Syringe (N...   

   Availability and Estimated Shortage Duration  Related Information  \
 0                            Product available                  NaN   

    Shortage Reason (per FDASIA)  
 0  Demand increase for the drug  ,
                                         Presentation  \
 0  0.1 mg/mL; 10 mL Ansyr syringe (NDC 0409-1630-10)   
 1  0.05 mg/mL; 5 mL Ansyr syringe (NDC 0409-9630-05)   
 2  0.1 mg/mL; 5 mL Lifeshield syringe (NDC 0409-4...   
 3  0.1 mg/mL; 10 mL Lifeshield syringe (NDC 0409-...   

         Availability and Estimated Shortage Duration  \
 0  Next delivery: Late October. Estimated recover...   
 1         Next delivery: TBD Estimated recovery: TBD   
 2                                          Available   
 3                                          Available   

                                  Related Information  \
 0  Please check with your wholesaler for availabl...   
 1  Please check with your wholesaler for availabl...   
 2               Shortage per Manufacturer: Available   
 3               Shortage per Manufacturer: Available   

   Shortage Reason (per FDASIA)  
 0                        Other  
 1                        Other  
 2                        Other  
 3                        Other  ,
                                Presentation  \
 0  0.4 mg/mL, 20 mL vial (NDC 0641-6006-10)   

   Availability and Estimated Shortage Duration  \
 0           West-Ward has available inventory.   

                                  Related Information  \
 0  Additional lots are scheduled to be manufactur...   

    Shortage Reason (per FDASIA)  
 0  Demand increase for the drug  ]
```

As you can see the list (or table?) has repeated columns: `Presentation`, `Availability and Estimated Shortage Duration`, `Related Information`, `Shortage Reason (per FDASIA)`, since the website has 3 different tables with the same columns. Therefore, my question is how to flat or normalize all the different tables or lists into a single one, more or less like this:

```
[                                        Presentation  \
 0  0.4 mg/mL, 1 mL single-dose vial, package of 2...   
 1  1 mg/mL, 1 mL single-dose vial, package of 25 ...   
 2  1 mg/mL; 10 mL Luer-Jet Prefilled Syringe (N... 
 3  0.1 mg/mL; 10 mL Ansyr syringe (NDC 0409-1630-10)   
 4  0.05 mg/mL; 5 mL Ansyr syringe (NDC 0409-9630-05)   
 5  0.1 mg/mL; 5 mL Lifeshield syringe (NDC 0409-4...   
 6  0.1 mg/mL; 10 mL Lifeshield syringe (NDC 0409-...   



   Availability and Estimated Shortage Duration  \
 0             Available for NDC 00517-0401-25.   
 1                                    Available  
 2                            Product available                  NaN   
 0  Next delivery: Late October. Estimated recover...   
 1         Next delivery: TBD Estimated recovery: TBD   
 2                                          Available   
 3                                          Available  
 0  0.4 mg/mL, 20 mL vial (NDC 0641-6006-10)   

   Availability and Estimated Shortage Duration  \
 0           West-Ward has available inventory.   


    Shortage Reason (per FDASIA)  
 0  Demand increase for the drug  


                                  Related Information  \
 0  American Regent is currently releasing the 0.4...   
 1  American Regent is currently releasing the 1mg...   
 0  Please check with your wholesaler for availabl...   
 1  Please check with your wholesaler for availabl...   
 2               Shortage per Manufacturer: Available   
 3               Shortage per Manufacturer: Available   
 0  Additional lots are scheduled to be manufactur...   


    Shortage Reason (per FDASIA)  
 0  Demand increase for the drug  
 1                         Other  ,



    Shortage Reason (per FDASIA)  
 0  Demand increase for the drug  ,
 0                        Other  
 1                        Other  
 2                        Other  
 3                        Other  ,
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) if `dfs` is list of `DataFrames`:

```
df = pd.concat(dfs)
```

Also you can use parameter `ignore_index=True` for avoid duplicates in index:

```
df = pd.concat(dfs, ignore_index=True)
```

Sample:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3],
                   'B':[4,5,6],
                   'C':[7,8,9]})

#print (df1)

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'A':[3,4,6],
                   'B':[2,3,4],
                   'C':[3,6,0]})

#print (df2)

df3 = pd.DataFrame({'A':[4,7,9],
                   'B':[3,4,5],
                   'C':[5,1,9]})

#print (df3)

dfs = [df1,df2,df3]
print (dfs)
[   A  B  C
0  1  4  7
1  2  5  8
2  3  6  9,    A  B  C
0  3  2  3
1  4  3  6
2  6  4  0,    A  B  C
0  4  3  5
1  7  4  1
2  9  5  9]
```

```
df = pd.concat(dfs)
print (df)
   A  B  C
0  1  4  7
1  2  5  8
2  3  6  9
0  3  2  3
1  4  3  6
2  6  4  0
0  4  3  5
1  7  4  1
2  9  5  9

df1 = pd.concat(dfs, ignore_index=True) 
print (df1)
   A  B  C
0  1  4  7
1  2  5  8
2  3  6  9
3  3  2  3
4  4  3  6
5  6  4  0
6  4  3  5
7  7  4  1
8  9  5  9
```